# Perl - remove carriage return and append next line

Tags: perl

What if I have a record in a otherwise good file that had a carriage return in it.

Ex:

```
1,2,3,4,5 ^M
,6,7,8,9,10
```

and I wanted to make it

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: I know you're new to this site, but it's customary to accept an answer and credit those that made good points.  You should also clarify as many people had questions in response to your vagueness.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have a string with a stray newline at the end that you want to get rid of, you can use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) on it (note that you can pass it an lvalue, so wrapping it around an assignment is legal):

```
my $string = $string2 = "blah\n";
chomp $string;

# this works too:
chomp(my $string3 = $string2);
```

Note that if the string has a trailing `"\r\n"`, chomp won't take the `\r` as well, unless you modify `$/`.

So if all of that is too complicated, and you need to remove all occurrences of `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r` (maybe you're processing lines from a variety of architectures all at once?), you can fall back to good old `tr`:

```
$string =~ tr/\r\n//d;
```

Comment: To clarify the issue, it may be a file with 100 lines, 99 of which are fine.  So I only want to append the next line if a carriage return exists.

Comment: @Dan: can you clarify how you are reading lines from the file?  You may be able to simply do:  `if ($line =~ /\r/) { chomp $line; $line .= <$infile>; }` to read in the next line and concatenate to the first.

Comment: The issue with `$string =~ tr/\r\n//d;` is that it will remove all occurrences of `\r\n` everywhere and not only the one at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a file that contains a ctrl-M (aka `\r` on some platforms):

```
$ cat input 
1,2,3
4,5,6
,7,8,9
10,11,12
```

This is explicit with `od`:

```
$ od -c input 
0000000   1   ,   2   ,   3  \n   4   ,   5   ,   6  \r  \n   ,   7   ,
0000020   8   ,   9  \n   1   0   ,   1   1   ,   1   2  \n
0000035
```

Remove each offending character and join its line with the next by running

```
$ perl -pe 's/\cM\cJ?//g' input 
1,2,3
4,5,6,7,8,9
10,11,12
```

or redirect to a new file with

```
$ perl -pe 's/\cM\cJ?//g' input >updated-input
```

or overwrite it in place (plus a backup in `input.bak`) with

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe 's/\cM\cJ?//g' input
```

Making the `\cJ` optional handles the case when a file ends with ctrl-M but not ctrl-J.

Answer (score 0):

s/[\r\n]//g

Only do this if you want to combine a line with the next.

Comment: This removes *all* carriage returns and all newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the carriage return is right before the line feed:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\r\n//' your_file_name
```

This will join only lines with a carriage return at the end of the line to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Every line is ended with some terminator sequence, either

- CRLF  (\r\n = 13, 10) on Windows/DOS
- CR    (\n = 13)       on  Unix
- LF    (\r = 10)       on MacOS

If some lines are OK, you should say from wich system the file comes or on wich system the perl script is executed, or the risk is to remove every end of line and merge all of your program lines...

As ^M is the CR character, if you see such a character at the end of a line and nothing special on other lines, you are probably using some kind of Unix (Linux ?) and some copy/paste has polluted one line with an additional \r at the end of line.

if this is the case :

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n$//g' filetomodify
```

will do the trick and merge only the line containing both CR and LF with the next line, leaving the other lines untounhed.

Answer (score -1):

#### More Information Needed

---

More information is needed about the underlying data and what your definition of `carriage return` is.  Is the data in Linux or Windows?  Really, do you mean carriage return/line feed, or just line feed?

---

#### Some Options:

- `$text =~ tr/\r//;` → this is the fastest method to weed out carriage returns
- `$text =~ tr/\n//;` → this is the fastest method to change newlines
- `$test =~ s/\n//s;`  → this is probably what you're looking for, which makes the text appear as one line and removes the internal `\n`

Comment: Neither of your `tr///` operations will do anything at all, and the `/s` modifier on `s///` has no effect, and it will remove exactly *one* newline.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for the preemptive down-vote, though I do appreciate you leaving a comment. Whatever I had there had worked (over half a decade ago). Transliteration could still work, but I forget how -- one hack might be to force a null byte: `tr/\n/\0/;` Perhaps I was introducing some clever trick, which hasn't stood the test of time, or even the changes of SO? -- your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: You're also correct about the single line modifier (`/s`) -- I believe I had inserted that in case he planned to do anything with the wildcard `.` match, thinking that it would be something for him to look up if he didn't understand it.  It's obvious a question like this for someone new to regex, so I took the liberty of inserting some educational curiosities for him to look up at a later time.