# finding split lines and removing the CRLF between them

Tags: perl, replace, sed

I apologize as this is a noob s// question, but I'm frustrated as to the inconsistency of operation across different applications/tools. I don't know enough about the differences. I've researched and looked at this below link's thread and have been banging my head against a wall for hours.

[Perl - remove carriage return and append next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214855/perl-remove-carriage-return-and-append-next-line)

The issue is that I'm data cleaning (boo) and I believe I have found a generic solution that reduces 7+ s// operations into one. But I can't get the operation to work via command line when it works in notepad++ and this online tool regex101.com.

Here is some similar data:

```
1429,12/6/2016,11:07:24 AM,T,527:472,281,2,176,-,205,Error,[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
anchorstring::anchorstring2 message payload[CR][LF]
important data here =999, source=001, xyz=687[CR][LF]
1430,12/6/2016,11:07:24 AM,T,527:472,281,11,1844,-,81,Message,writing data[CR][LF]
```

I added the [CR][LF] because using notepad++ I can see them. I cannot get rid of them via a command line perl expression.

Obviously the three lines that don't start with a number are bad lines that need to be pulled back into line 1429.

I've tried:

```
perl -p0e "s/(\cM\cJ)?\cM\cJ(^[^\d].+)/\2 /g" output.csv > output2.csv

perl -p0e "s/(\r\n)?\r\n(^[^\d].+)/\2 /g" output.csv > output2.csv

sed -r s/"\r\n(^[^\d].+)"/"\1 "/g output.csv > output2.csv

perl -p0e "s/\n(^[^\d]+.+)/\1 /g" output.csv > output2.csv
```

ad nauseum...

The frustrating thing is that it works when I use the regex find&replace operator in notepad++ and the regex101 tool says it should find and replace it.

`perl -p00e "s/(,Error,)\n\n/\1/g" output.csv > output2.csv` worked to get rid of the CRLFs but that anchors to "Error" and not all of the splits have that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use this to remove **CR** & **LF**
`$_ =~ s/\x{0A}//g; # remove line feed`
`$_ =~ s/\x{0D}//g; # remove carriage return`

Comment: You didn't ask a question :-) Do you want to replace sequential CRLFs with a single CRLF? Or are you trying to do something more complex?

Comment: I....didn't ask a question. My bad. I guess my question is how do I know when to which syntax? And if I can't determine which syntax, what's the simplest expression that I can work "forwards" from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get rid of all splits.

```
perl -p0777e "s/\n\n?([^0-9])/ \1/g" output.csv > output2.csv
```

Comment: `-0777` is the proper way of reading the entire file. `-0` only reads until a a NUL.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If the csv file contains null values it should be `-0777` to be sure to read entire file. I've corrected the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was experimenting with the minimum code that would actually change the output2 file and what I got so far was `perl -p0e "s/\n\n(.+)\n/\1 /g" output.csv > output2.csv`. It didn't like `^(.+)` or `[^\d]` or `[^0-9]` which was really surprising to me. I tried out your option change and it appeared to work great. I have to iron out a couple outliers, but I believe that option change was the big problem. Just so you know I upvoted you, but my rep stinks.